# Few doubts regarding waves acting on strings

Tags: waves

First let's take a look at the image  below

[image]

XY and YZ are two **different** strings. Strings XY and YZ are connected each other at **Y.**

---

Now what I do is, I create a wave pulse by shaking the composite  string from the end X by   using my hand. Assume the wave pulse that I am created is  same  as the one in the below  image.(Note: Assume I hold the string with my hand until this  experiment is finished )

[image]

So what I want to know is what would be the resultant shape of wave when it reaches Y on strings XY and   YZ, if

**1. Mass per unit length of string XY > Mass per unit length of string
    YZ.**

**2.  Mass per unit length of string XY < Mass per unit length of string
    YZ.**

---

And further I want to know how a pulse  that is slanted to one side behave under these conditions (The conditions that mentioned just above this paragraph )

Like these,

[image]

[image].

Comment: I'm pretty sure the slant is simply to show the direction of movement of the wave..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are going to get a reflected and transmitted wave, the two properties that change from the original input wave are the amplitude and wavelength of the two waves.
I am going to use 1 and 2 to denote the input side of the string and transmission side respectively.

### Amplitude

The amplitude is determined by these two formulae:

$$A_r=A_i \frac{Z_1 - Z_2}{Z_1+Z_2}$$

$$A_t=A_i\frac{2Z_1}{Z_1+Z_2}$$

Where $Z=\sqrt{Tμ}$; $μ$ is the mass per unit length of the string and $T$ is the tension in the string.

As the tension has to be the same all the way down the string we can remove $T$ from the above formulae for $A_r$ and $A_t$.

$$A_r=A_i \frac{\sqrt{μ_1} - \sqrt{μ_2}}{\sqrt{μ_1}+\sqrt{μ_2}}$$

$$A_t=A_i\frac{2\sqrt{μ_1}}{\sqrt{μ_1}+\sqrt{μ_2}}$$

### Wavelength

$$c=\sqrt{\frac{T}{μ}}=fλ$$

Now at the intersection the waves have to agree, so $f$(frequency of the wave) is the same for the transmission wave and the reflection wave. $T$ has already been establish as the same through out.

$$λ_1 = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{T}{μ1}}}{f}$$

$$λ_2 = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{T}{μ2}}}{f}$$

This won't change the reflected wave as it does not change medium. But as the transmitted wave goes from the medium with density $μ_1$ to $μ_2$ it will change wavelength.

From these formulae we can now outline the two cases.

**Case 1($μ1 > μ2$)**

$A_r$ is negative and less than $A_i$(in magnitude).

$A_t$ is greater than $A_i$.

$λ_t$ is greater than $λ_r$.

**Case 2($μ1 < μ2$)**

$A_r$ positive and still less than $A_i$.

$A_t$ positive and less than $A_i$.

$λ_t$ is less than $λ_r$.

**Slanting**

Also the slanting will look the same except for the slant.

Comment: Use math notation, when you insert mathematical terms. This improves the readability of your answer by a lot.

Comment: Sorry, realised after reading a few other physics answers. Is it like LaTex syntax?

Comment: Yes, it's the same syntax. You just have to encapsulate the formula in a single \$ to include it in a line of text or with a double \$ to place the equation in a separate line.

Comment: Edited to use proper maths formatting now. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @james : How the slanting thing work?And I wanna know another thing, isn't there any chance for the reflected impulse to get inverted.

Comment: On the subject of the slanting I think any pattern of disturbance gets distorted by having its pattern scaled at rights to and along the direction of travel. You can regard a slanted wave as being made up of infinitely many sin waves of increasing frequency. So as long as they all still travel at the same speed and each is affected in the same way the shape should still be the same, but altered in the way shown. Also by negative amplitude of the reflected wave in the first case I mean inversion of the reflected wave. But I don't think there is any chance for inversion of the outgoing wave.